# How to creating function with given code in C++?

Tags: c++

Giving that a function CreatCustomer() that create a Customer. Prototype:

```
Customer*CreatCustomer(const string&name, const string&id, const string&pin)
```

And the given code is like below.The structure is done by myself.

The question is how to create a function by using this given code and prototype.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Customer
{
string CustomerName;
string UserID;
string Pin;
};
int main()
{
Customer* Mary = CreateCustomer("Mary Jones", "235718", "5074");
Customer* John = CreateCustomer("John Smith", "375864", "3251");
}
```

Comment: Perhaps first opening a book and read about C++, or look at some existing code ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all in your case you don't even need that function, you can just do:

```
Customer Mary { "Mary Jones", "235718", "5074" };
Customer John { "John Smith", "375864", "3251" };
```

But if you really need to, you should use a constructor:

```
struct Customer
{
    std::string CustomerName;
    std::string UserID;
    std::string Pin;
    Customer(std::string a, std::string b, std::string c)
        : CustomerName(a)
        , UserID(b)
        , Pin(c)
        {}
};
```

The reason I'm not telling you how to do this directly is because the pointer in the return type suggests me that someone told you to use dynamic memory allocation inside the function and return a pointer to it. That's an **awfully bad idea**.

But since the foot is yours and I'm not here to babysit a shotgun, here's how you shoot:

```
Customer* CreateCustomer(const string&name, const string&id, const string&pin) {
    return new Customer { name, id, pin };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Customer*CreatCustomer( const string &name, const string &id, const string &pin )
{
   return new Customer { name, id, pin };
}
```

Or if the compiler does not support initializer lists then

```
Customer*CreatCustomer( const string &name, const string &id, const string &pin )
{
   Customer *c = new Customer;

   c.->CustomerName = name;
   c->UserID = id;
   c->Pin = pid;

   return c;
}
```